# Как правильно сказать мне болит голова или у меня болит голова

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно
Мне болит голова
Или
У меня болит голова

Answer (score 4):

Правильно только ***"У меня болит голова"***. Эта форма примерно соответствует английской конструкции "There is ... at mine", но используется много чаще: в отношении наличия чего-либо у лица, о котором говорится.

"Мне" используется в других случаях, обычно с модальными глаголами, возвратными и глаголами чувственного состояния: ***мне надо, мне хочется, мне думается***,  причем многие такие формы - чисто разговорные.